# Tkinter exe is not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, scipy, exe, cx-freeze

Currently, I'm working on a Tkinter program. This program works fine, but after i convert it to a exe file, i encounter a problem. The code is as follows: 
import tkinter as tk

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy 
import pandas as pd
import math 
import os 
import numpy.core._methods, numpy.lib.format 
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Calculatepage,Final):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            self.geometry("700x400")

            self.wm_title('Test')
            self["bg"]="white"

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.update_page()
        frame.tkraise()    

    def show_frame2(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]

        frame.tkraise()

        frame.update_page()
        self.update()
        page=self.get_page(cont) 
        value = page.value

        frame = self.frames[Final]
        frame.update_page(value)
        frame.tkraise()      


    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self["bg"]="white"
        frame2 = tk.Frame(height=150, bd=10,bg="green")
        frame2.pack(fill=tk.X)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Calculate', width=25, height=2, bg="green",fg="white",command=lambda: controller.show_frame2(Calculatepage))

        button1.place(x=250,y=100)

    def update_page(self): # empty method but I need it
            pass   

class Calculatepage(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self["bg"]="white"
        self.controller=controller

        self.label1=tk.Label(self, text="Loading...",bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 10")
        self.label1.pack()

        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="",bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 20")
        self.label2.pack()

    def update_page(self):

        A = 10 
        b = 2
        self.value= scipy.linalg.solve(A, b)

class Final(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self["bg"]="white"
        self.controller=controller

        label1=tk.Label(self, text="output is equal to:",bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 10")
        label1.pack()

        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="",bg="white",fg="green",font="verdana 20")
        self.label2.pack()

    def update_page(self,xvalue):

        output = xvalue 

        self.label2.config(text ="%s"%(output)) 

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

As you can see, in this example i do have a start screen. When the button is pressed, a calculation is made. While this is happening, the user will get a screen with the message "Loading...". After the calculation is made, the output will be displayed on a new screen. As desribed, when i run this program in python it works fine. I also can normally convert the program to an exe file. However, when i run the exe file, the program will stay on the page with "Loading..." (Calculationpage) and never continue to the last display page. I do get the following error: `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'linalg'`. Does anybody know how to solve this?

The cx_freeze file I'm using is:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib 
import os 

base = None 


executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Test.py",base=base,icon="test.ico")]    

cx_Freeze.setup(
        name = "User",
        option = { "build_exe":{"packages": ["tkinter","matplotlib","scipy.linalg"]}},
        version="0.01",
        executables=executables)
```

Comment: To use `scipy.linalg`, your code must explicitly import `scipy.linalg`, not just `scipy`.  So change `import scipy` to `import scipy.linalg`.